# Eclipse French support

Tags: eclipse, unicode, internationalization

I need to enter some French chars in eclipse. How do I configure eclipse to enter French? I do have all the fonts that come with default eclipse packaging.

Comment: What happens if you just type them? Or use the character picker? Then there's also the \u1234 Unicode escape sequence for Java.

Comment: I have fonts installed on my machine. Also eclipse default encoding is set to UTF-8. In wordpad, I can type in french by just using Left Alt + Shift key to switch language. How do I do that for eclipse? I also tried chaning fonts in eclipse.

Comment: Just added a small addition to my answer, regarding keyboard locale switching ability.

Answer (score 5):

Preference / General / Workspace / Text file encoding

In my configuration, I see Cp1252 (probably set after my OS current setup) and have no problem with any French character. UTF-8 is a more general setting which will accommodate any OS language setup.

As noted in this [blog entry](http://softwaredevscott.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!1A9E939F7373F3B7!493.entry), this should be UTF-8 by default, for encoding unlimited number of universal (Unicode) code points instead of a specific encoding grid like Cp1252.
(see [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) from Joel Spolsky)

[image]

The OP add:

> Also eclipse default encoding is set to UTF-8.

Good!

> In wordpad, I can type in French by just using <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to switch language. How do I do that for eclipse?

By typing the same combination: it will change the locale of the keyboard.
On my azerty keyboard, when I click within an eclipse editor (like a Java editor), I will see 'q' when I will type 'a', because the keyboard will be mapped to a qwerty one.

Comment: did I misunderstand the OP's question?  I read it not as how to configure eclipse to accept the characters (which you and I are in agreement that it does by default), but how to actually enter said characters, which is addressed in my answer.  I have difficulty reading it such that your answer actually answers the question.

Comment: @rmeador: I very well might have misinterpreted the question. Hopefully, the OP will clarify it.

Comment: I have fonts installed on my machine. Also eclipse default encoding is set to UTF-8. In wordpad, I can type in french by just using Left Alt + Shift key to switch language. How do I do that for eclipse? I also tried chaning fonts in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Eclipse, like most (all?) Java applications, uses UTF8 as its normal character set.  Thus, it is not Eclipse that needs to be changed to enter French characters, but your operating system (specifically the keyboard layout).  You'll probably find it easier to figure out whatever escape sequences your OS uses to enter characters not representable on your keyboard.  On Windows, you can do this with the Character Map utility available under Accessories.  I'm not sure how to do it on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for accents. it shows you how to have accents if that's the help you requesting 
https://www.spanishdict.com/answers/282262/how-to-type-spanish-letters-and-accents-from-paralee

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.